# Ship assets with your angular library

Tags: angular, assets, angular-library, nx-workspace

I'm [building an angular components library](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/add-file-upload/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/src), using an NX workspace.
ATM I'm implementing a file-uploader. This uploader will contain an image (svg), which should be included in the library/package.

All solutions I find on the internet, require the consumer of the library to **update their `angular.json` apps section**. For me, this is an absolute no-go. Here's some of the resources I found explaining this:

- [Create Nx Libs with Assets](https://juristr.com/blog/2020/05/nx-libs-with-assets/)
- [How to include assets from library](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/88)

I already modified my ng-package.json by adding the `assets` field:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/example-ng-bootstrap",
  "assets": ["./assets"],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

Tried adding

```
"targets:build:options:assets": [
  "libs/example-ng-bootstrap/src/assets"
]
```

to the lib angular.json section (project.json - NX angular.json V2 style), which doesn't build at all.

Tried following ng-package.json config:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/example-ng-bootstrap",
  "assets": ["/dist/libs/example-ng-bootstrap/lib/assets"],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

As of the included links, it does explain how to build an NX schematic that does this for you, but then anyone who builds an app (angular workspace style) that consumes this library will probably not be able to use this schematic.

Someone else (in the github link) also mentions that some solutions only work for apps within the same NX workspace, which off course doesn't help anyone either.

I'm puzzled as to why assets delivered by libraries don't work out-of-the-box, or without modifications to the consuming application. You may as well deliver them through a USB-stick... I would be fine providing an angular schematic though.

Also, I'd rather design the icon through css, than the consumer having to update files of his own, but I'd still like to know if there's a good solution to this.

Does anyone have experience on how to deal with this in a professional way?

### Edit

It seems hard to find information on how to build and publish angular schematics using NX, but [this seems to be a useful link](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2664)

Comment: [Explained here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my final `ng-package.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/mycompany-ng-bootstrap",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  },
  "assets": [
    "./src/assets/**",
    "./src/styles/**",
    "./_bootstrap.scss"
  ]
}
```

After publishing the dist files, for example to NPM, I'm able to reference the assets in the `angular.json`

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/@mintplayer/ng-bootstrap/_bootstrap.scss",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

### EDIT 14/04/2023

It seems that now you have to add [the following](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/package.json#L10-L12) to your library **package.json**:

```
"exports": {
  "./bootstrap.scss": "./_bootstrap.scss"
},
```

In other applications, you can then include these styles like this:

```
"styles": [
  "@example/ng-bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
  "src/styles.scss"
],
```

[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#subpath-exports)

Comment: How do you import `_bootstrap.scss` in the final application that uses this library?

Comment: For my project, I've explained it [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap).

Comment: My `ng build my-lib` command puts the library into `dist` folder, not into `node_modules`. Why is that?

Comment: Because my package is published to NPM, and can be installed with `npm i @example/package`. After this, the dist files end up in your application's `node_modules/@example/package`. Because I specified `assets` in my `ng-package.json`, these files end up in the package too, so you can import them like I did

Comment: I've added more details

Comment: I see, so how do I use the assets from dist directory without publishing?

Comment: Haven't done that yet. But did you setup an NX workspace or simple angular workspace? Anyway I think you should be able to do the same from the moment you add a [path mapping to your workspace tsconfig.json](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/tsconfig.base.json#L21). This allows me to [use the resource in my application](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/styles.scss)

Comment: If you're building a monorepo like I did, just take a look at the project in the link I posted. If you want the code of your library seperated from your application, you will need to publish the package to a feed, either your private feed on Github or I think you can just configure a new feed pointing to a folder on your drive too

Comment: I have exactly the same of your monorepo setup, but just not publishing to npm. I still cannot do `@import ‘~@my-lib/styles/themes.scss’;` So my options are `@import ‘../../../dist/my-lib/styles/styles.scss` or using a path in tsconfig.json?

Comment: Yepper, that's right. I tried the same, but as you can see, [I commented it out](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/styles.scss#L1). For applications within the same monorepo, I would just stick to the level-up reference... I don't think a path mapping in `tsconfig.base.json` would help here, but I would be interested if someone got this to work...

Comment: How to include 3rd party css from global node_modules into assets in ng-package.json?

Comment: Just make this 3rd party library a `peerDependency`. The consumer should install your package using `npm i @example/my-package`, which installs the peerDependencies too