# How to export @angular/material styles from a user lib(NX) to the nx with MFA workspace apps

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, webpack-module-federation, nrwl, angular-module-federation

I have created an [Angular Micro Frontends with Dynamic Module Federation](https://nx.dev/recipes/module-federation/dynamic-module-federation-with-angular) by following the official documentation.

I use the following command to create the workspace:

`npx create-nx-workspace demo-app --preset=empty`

`npm install --save-dev @nrwl/angular`

`nx g @nrwl/angular:host host-app --dynamic`

`nx g @nrwl/angular:remote remote-app --host=host-app --port=4201`

And, I also created a custom-lib using the below command:

`nx generate @nrwl/angular:library custom-lib --directory=libs --buildable --publishable --importPath=@monorepo/my-custom-lib`

After all, you can see the folder structure below:

```
apps/
  - host-app/
    - src/
        - styles.scss
    - project.json
    ...
  - remote-app/
    - src/
        - styles.scss
    - project.json
  ...
libs/
  - custom-lib/
    - src/
        - lib/
            - components/
                - header-component/
            - custom-lib.module.ts
        - index.ts
    - package.json
      ...
  - themes/
    - mat-styles.scss
package.json
nx.json
...
```

Furthermore, I have installed `@angular/material` in custom-lib and kept *@angular/material* in ***peerDependencies*** in `libs/custom-lib/package.json` to create custom components and created a `HeaderComponent` using @angular/material.

I have installed `@angular/material` in the custom-lib(*not in the host/remote app*) and imported/exported material modules.

I am trying to export/reuse the @angular/material styles in the apps(host or remote) For that I have followed the below steps:

1. I have imported `indigo-pink.css` in `libs/themes/mat-styles.scss` file.

   **libs/themes/mat-styles.scss**

   ```
   @import './styles//variables';
   @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css'; <-- IMPORTED

   span {
     font-weight: 400;
     font-size: 1.125rem;
     line-height: 1.75rem;
   }
   ```
2. I have updated `project.json` configuration in `apps/host-app/project.json` file.

   ```
   ...
   "targets": {
     "build": {
       "executor": "@nrwl/angular:webpack-browser",
       "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
       "options": {
         ...
         "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
         "assets": [
           "apps/host-app/src/favicon.ico",
           "apps/host-app/src/assets",
         ],
         "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
           "includePaths": ["libs/themes"] <-- INCLUDED GLOBAL STYLES
         },
         "styles": ["apps/host-app/src/styles.scss"],
         "scripts": [],
         "customWebpackConfig": {
           "path": "apps/host-app/webpack.config.js"
         }
       },
     },
   }
   ```
3. Next, I have **imported** the  `mat-styles.scss` into `apps/host-app/src/styles.scss` file.

   ```
   @import 'mat-styles.scss';
   ```
4. I also added `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` in `apps/host-app/src/index.html` file.
5. **Here is the problem, I am getting the following errors:**

   > ```
   > ./apps/host-app/src/styles.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
   > Error: Can't resolve '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/Users/IAM/Movies/demo-app/apps/host-app/src'
   >
   > ./apps/host-app/src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
   > HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
   > Error: Can't resolve '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css' in '/Users/IAM/Movies/demo-app/apps/host-app/src'
   > ```

   **NOTE:** in case if I remove/comment *@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';* in *mat-styles.scss* then I can able to export normal styles(span and any other normal styles that I create) into apps.

**So, only thing is that I can not export @angular/material styles from libs to apps. How can I export/reuse these styles in apps?**

Thanks and any help appreciated!

Comment: I created a SCSS file myself, and [added it to the assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600948/ship-assets-with-your-angular-library). Then you can refer to this stylesheet [like this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/project.json#L31) if from the same NX workspace, or using `@example/ng-bootstrap/styles.scss` if from another workspace

Comment: Hi @Pieterjan, Thank you for your response!
I have tested what you suggested, and unfortunately, this solution is not working. I am [linking my project here](https://github.com/naithagoni/nx-dynamic-module-federation-demo), could you please check this out? I am basically trying to export @angular/material styles from my lib to an app(dashboard).